# why does $T(1,0) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})?$ Why not $T(1,0) = (\frac{1}{ 2},-\frac{1}{ 2})?$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$  be the linear transformation that takes a point $(x, y)$ and projects
it orthogonally onto the line $y = −x$

If $b$ is the  standard basis  for $\mathbb{R}^2$ .find $[T]_b $?

**My attempt**: In this [link](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eqadeer/teaching/F17Math110/Worksheet%203%20Solutions.pdf) Page no : $6$, I found the answer.

It written that

> $$T(1,0) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})$$

> $$T(0,1) = (-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})$$

Actually I got  $$T(x,y)=proj_w(x,y)= \left(\frac{(x-y)}{2} , \frac{(-x+y)}{2}\right)$$

**My confusion** : why does $T(1,0) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})?$ Why not $T(1,0) = (\frac{1}{ 2},-\frac{1}{ 2})?$

Comment: Try to draw the actual projection and use Pythagoras theorem

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate more, @TonyPizza? I don't understand

Comment: You have to do orthogonal projection on some line. So first draw $X-Y$ plane, then draw that line. Take the points you are concerned with like $(1,0), (0,1)$ and then project orthogonally to corresponding line. Doing this you will understand why the projection is what it is and not $(1/2,-1/2)$.

Comment: Actually what you've done is correct.  Must be an error in the textbook.

Comment: I completely agree with you @HosamH